# Force User To Like FB Page Before Visiting My Website

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-like

As part of a website that I am developing, I have a Like Gate Page that I want to use in order to force my site visitors to press the `like` button before they are redirected to the site homepage.

When a Liker visitor comes back for the LIKE Gate page he/she should be redirected automatically to the website homepage (he/she already pressed like).

Important:

1. The whole website including the Like Gate is not found in a Facebook App/Page Tab!
2. It is OK to ask the user to login before he/she can press the Like button.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in your web page you could implement Facebook login and get user's permission to see his/her [likes](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#likes). Get said likes from Graph API, see if your page is in the list and depending on that, either show your web page, or redirect user to your facebook page. You will need `user_likes` permission for that.

Answer (score -1):

By using Facebook Javascript SDK Methods FB.Event.subscribe, FB.getLoginStatus, FB.api, authResponse, pages.isFan, access.token and Javascript SDK and a little bit PHP SDK.
I saw one, almost perfect that can be site-integrated, fully-explained, and free in this blog: http://daneworx.blogspot.com/2014/02/how-to-force-users-to-like-your-page.html